# How to add column to nested table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, nested-table

I have table with nested table, and I want to add another column to **the nested table**.
Is it possible? If it is, what is the syntax? couldn't find it anywhere..

Consider this example:

```
CREATE TYPE address_t AS OBJECT (
   street  VARCHAR2(30),
   city    VARCHAR2(20),
   zip     NUMBER );
 
CREATE TYPE addresses_nested IS TABLE OF address_t;

CREATE TABLE customers (
   id NUMBER,
   address addresses_nested )
   NESTED TABLE address STORE AS customer_addresses;
```

It Creates the the table "customers" with nested table "addresses_nested":
[image]

Can u give an example how to add column to "addresses_nested" if possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I if followed correctly, you want to add an attribute to the underlying type. If so, you can use the `alter type` statement:

```
alter type address_t add attribute phone varchar2(12) cascade;
```

Comment: Nice! thanks it worked.I tried to do many things on the table but didn't think of the type...